# maven plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar

Will all the jars used by the project added automatically to build path of project in eclipse by adding the maven plugin to eclipse(m2eclipse)? If not added automatically what should be done to get the jars into build path?

Answer (score 1):

> Will all the jars used by the project added automatically to build
>   path of project in eclipse by adding the maven plugin to
>   eclipse(m2eclipse)?

All the JARs that you define as dependencies in pom.xml will be added automatically to the Eclipse build path.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is set up as a Maven project in Eclipse, then yes.  Also this assumes that your settings.xml file and pom.xml are correct.

If it is an exsisting non-maven project, you will need to use the context menus to convert it into a maven project before the dependencies are added.

Comment: i'm using maven to run this project.. so is that enough to add maven plugin to eclipse to get all the jars into eclipse build path?

Comment: i'm using maven s/w.. i didn't set my project as a maven projet? How to know if a project is setup as a maven project in eclipse?